# low performance by DBINFO('sqlca.sqlerrd1') of Informix 9.40

Tags: sql, performance, informix

After a row was inserted I read the serial of inserted row with  DBINFO('sqlca.sqlerrd1'). The select proccess takes a lot of time ( 5 - 10 sec ).
For the analyse I switch on the sqexplain before the insert command

```
set explain on;
load from x  insert into  transaction;
SELECT distinct dbinfo('sqlca.sqlerrd1') FROM transaction;
```

The output :

```
QUERY:
        ------
        SELECT distinct dbinfo('sqlca.sqlerrd1') FROM transaction

        Estimated Cost: 353490
        Estimated # of Rows Returned: 10

          1) cms.transaction: SEQUENTIAL SCAN
```

I perform the update statistics:

```
update statistics medium for table transaction;
```

but this didn't help. Why the SQL-Engine perform the sequential scan?
If I search with :

```
SELECT MAX (sernr ) from transaction;
```

(where sernr is serial field ) the SQL-Engine search with index.
Here the output:

```
QUERY:
        ------
        SELECT MAX (sernr ) from transaction

        Estimated Cost: 4
        Estimated # of Rows Returned: 1

           1) cms.transaction: INDEX PATH

           (1) Index Keys: sernr   (Key-Only)  (Aggregate)  (Serial, fragments: ALL)
```

What I should to do for increase of performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use

```
SELECT distinct dbinfo('sqlca.sqlerrd1') FROM transaction;
```

you are in fact reading all the rows in the table `transaction`, returning the `DBINFO('sqlca.sqlerrd1')` value in each row. Since the value is always the same, the distinct will only return 1 row.

You only want 1 row, so you can use something like this:

```
SELECT DBINFO('sqlca.sqlerrd1') FROM systables WHERE tabid = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks Luis! The answer is correct. I have used the following command

SELECT first 1 dbinfo('sqlca.sqlerrd1') FROM transaction